# SQL Identify Unique User from multiple columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there anyway to create a unique identifier column (user) for a user so that if Email, User_ID or Subscription_ID is a match between any of the rows then I will be able to group by and aggregate by this unique identifier later? The unique identifier doesn't have to be incrementing but I thought that could be a way of implementing it.

```
Data which could call subscriptions table:
|Email         |User_ID    |  Subscription_ID   |
|--------------|-----------|--------------------|
|12@gmail.com  |20         |  56                |
|12@gmail.com  |30         |  86                |
|13@gmail.com  |20         |  96                |
|14@gmail.com  |22         |  96                | 
|15@gmail.com  |80         |  12                |

Desired Result:
|Email         |User_ID    |  Subscription_ID   | User |
|--------------|-----------|--------------------|------|
|12@gmail.com  |20         |  56                | 1    |
|12@gmail.com  |30         |  86                | 1    |
|13@gmail.com  |20         |  96                | 1    |
|14@gmail.com  |22         |  96                | 1    |
|15@gmail.com  |80         |  12                | 2    |
```

Comment: Can you explain with more details the logic in the sample data?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I have updated the table now. The first 4 rows all have a common value in one of the columns with each other. The first and the second row have the same value in the "Email" column. The 1st and the 3rd column shares the same value in the "User_ID" column and the 4th row shares the same "Subscription_ID" as the 3rd row so they should all be assigned the same "User" ID as they share at least 1 column value in common. Where as row 5 has nothing in common with any of the other rows so it gets a different "User" ID.